# jscs validateIndentation with spaces .editorconfig

Tags: jscs

Having this .editorconfig:

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

what's the syntax for .jscsrc
I know for tab is like

```
"validateIndentation": "\t",
```

but what's the syntax for 4 spaces ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for spaces is to just use an integer, so:

`"validateIndentation": 4,`

Relevant excerpt from [the docs](http://jscs.info/rule/validateIndentation.html):

> validateIndentation
>
> Validates indentation for switch statements and block statements
>
> Types: `Integer`, `String` or `Object`
>
> Values:
>
> `Integer`: A positive number of spaces